# How can I access object created by factory method?

Tags: java, design-patterns, instance, factory-pattern

My question is how to access instance cretead via Factory method that had no name
This is my code

```
    public abstract class Vertex <T>{

int vertexId ;
T vertexValue ;

public  abstract  T computeVertexValue();}
```

```
    public class ImageVertex extends Vertex<Map<String, Instance>>{


public ImageVertex(int id ) {
    this.vertexId=id;
}

@Override
public Map<String, Instance> computeVertexValue() {
//  
}
```

```
    public abstract class AbstractVertexFactory<T extends Vertex>  {

public abstract  T createVertex(int id);}
```

```
    public class ImageFactory extends AbstractVertexFactory<ImageVertex> {

@Override
public ImageVertex createVertex(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageVertex imVertex=new ImageVertex(id);
    imVertex.computeVertexValue();
    return imVertex;
}}
```

```
    public class ImageFactorySimulator {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    AbstractVertexFactory<ImageVertex> immFactory = new ImageFactory();

    ImageVertex imVertex = immFactory.createVertex(1);}}
```

How can I from the simulator class or any other class  access to my ImageVertex instance that had an id equal to 1?

Comment: Pass that object to the constructor of the object you want to use it in?

Comment: I need to put Vertex that had same proprities into HyperEdge
for example ImageVertex(1) may belong to various HypeEdge

Comment: @TheCat  How to pass it in form of immFactory.createVertex(1)? 
it considered every time as a new Object

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get the same instance when calling `createVertex` with the same id? if so, you have to create a kind of repository. you can use a `List` to store your instances

Comment: Just pass the created object `imVertex` to the constructor of the `HyperEdge`s that need this vertex. Without seeing more code it's hard to suggest anything else.

Comment: imVertex may belong to more than one hyperEdge 
and I have more than 1000 imVertex